# How to apply angular js $scope objects to a partial loaded using jquery.load() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, partials

In my application I am loading an html partial using something like :

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $('#parentElement').load('/partials/temp1');
});
```

The template being loaded is something like :

```
<p style="background-color:black; color:white; margin:20px; padding:20px;">A simple 1 temp child - {{items[0]}}</p>
          <div style="background-color:gray; color:white;">Html contents also works ok!!!</div>
          <div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
          <p>
            Make the fox
            <button type="button" onclick="alert('Jump!!');">jump</button>
          </p>
```

BTW the `"#parentElement"` is wrapped within the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` directive `div`s

The template is getting loaded fine but `{{items[0]}}` `$scope` object is not getting rendered by Angular.js am I doing something wrong here?

Please guide

Comment: where is the scope coming from?

Comment: you need to [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it - http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html

Comment: The scope is coming from the controller which is wrapped around the parent div of "#parentElement"